# Colored function with pyplot.fill_between() in Python

Tags: matplotlib, plot

I want a shaded figure, but I don't know how to do it

```
 plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 3.50]
 plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

 def g(x):
     return np.sqrt(x/4) 

 def f(x):
    return 0.5
 
  x = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 1000)
  y = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 1000)
  plt.xlim([0, 1.08])
  plt.ylim([0, 0.55])
  plt.plot(x, g(x),  color='blue')
  
  plt.fill_between(x, g(x), color='green', step="pre", alpha=0.9)
  plt.fill_between(x,f(x), color='pink', step="pre", alpha=0.6)

  plt.xlabel('$\omega_q N$',  fontsize=14, weight='bold') 
  plt.ylabel('$g$', fontsize=14, weight='bold') 

  plt.show()
```

I get this picture
[image]

But i want this one  [image]

Comment: You can use `plt.fill_between(x,g(x),f(x), color='pink', step="pre", alpha=0.6)` to fill between `f` and `g`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the updated code to create the plot as you mentioned. There are multiple changes, so please refer to the comments on the changes... You can adjust the colors or line size, etc. to make it the way you want it.

```
plt.rcParams["figure.figsize"] = [7.50, 4.50]  ## Increased hieght a little
plt.rcParams["figure.autolayout"] = True

def g(x):
     return np.sqrt(x/4) 

def f(x):
    return 0.5

x = np.linspace(0, 1.0, 1000)
y = np.linspace(0, 0.5, 1000)
plt.xlim([0, 1.08])
plt.ylim([0, 0.55])
plt.plot(x, g(x),  color='blue')

#Color the orange section - note alpha=1
plt.fill_between(x, g(x), color='#AEDBAE', step="pre", alpha=1)
#Color the green section - note alpha=1
plt.fill_between(x,g(x),f(x), color='#F18860', step="pre", alpha=1)

#Draw blue horizontal lines - solid and dashes
plt.axhline(y=0.5, xmin=0, xmax=1/1.08, linewidth=2, color='blue')
plt.axhline(y=0.5, xmin=1/1.08, xmax=1, linewidth=2, color='blue', ls='--')

#Draw grey dotted vertical lines
plt.axvline(x=1, ymin=0, ymax=0.5/0.55, linewidth=1.5, color='darkgray', ls=':')
#Draw the single gray dot where the lines intersect -> zorder is to make sure the gray dot is on top
plt.scatter(1, 0.5, color="darkgray", s=50, zorder=10) 

import matplotlib.patches as patches
#Add the slanted black lines - called hatches
p = patches.Rectangle((0,0.5), 1.08, 0.05, linewidth=0, fill=None, hatch='/')
plt.gca().add_patch(p)

#Add the fading / gradient green to white on the right end of the plot from 1.0 to 1.1
from matplotlib import cm
from matplotlib.colors import LinearSegmentedColormap
cm = LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list("Custom", ["#AEDBAE","#FFFFFF"], N=20)
mat = np.indices((10,10))[1]
plt.imshow(mat, cmap = cm, extent=[1, 1.1, 0, 0.5], alpha = 1, aspect = "auto")

#Remove plot top line (despine) 
plt.gca().spines['top'].set_visible(False)

#Add text in each section
plt.text(0.2, 0.3, 'Superradiant \n Phase', ha='center', fontsize=20, color='white')
plt.text(0.6, 0.15, 'Normal \n phase', ha='center', fontsize=16, color='black')
plt.text(0.5, 0.55, 'Unbound region', ha='center', fontsize=22, color='black')

plt.xlabel('$\omega_q N$',  fontsize=14, weight='bold') 
plt.ylabel('$g$', fontsize=14, weight='bold') 
plt.show()
```

[image]